# Design Patterns, override a method without need to re compile / relink

Tags: java, design-patterns

We are building a product that needs to run on production environments. We need to modify some of the functionality of a existing library. The existing library has class's and methods, we need to override 1 or more methods so that the caller uses our overriden methods instead of the original library.

OriginalLibrary

```
package com.original.library ;
public class OriginalLibrary {
    public int getValue() {
        return 1 ;
    }
    public int getAnotherValue() {
        return 1 ;
    }
}
```

Original Client

```
public class MyClient {
    private OriginalLibraryClass originalLibraryObject ;
    public MyClient () {
        originalLibraryObject = new OriginalLibraryClass() ;
        System.out.println(originalLibraryObject.getValue()) ;
        System.out.println(originalLibraryObject.getAnotherValue()) ;
    }
}
```

**Output**

1

2

Now, I need to change `getValue()` to return `3`, instead of `1`

**Needed Output**

3

2

```
package com.original.library.improved ;
    public class OriginalLibrary extends com.original.library.OriginalLibrary {
        public int getValue() {
            return 3 ;
        }
        public int getAnotherValue() {
            return super.getAnotherValue() ;
        }
}
```

If I do the above, I need to tell my `Original Client` to reorder and use my new `com.original.library.improved` jar file **before** `com.original.library`.

I am almost convinced that this is the most `non intrusive way` to launch my improved services over and above the `OriginalLibrary`. I would have preferred a solution where I need to tell the customer to just add my jar file, no need to recompile, relink your client code.

Similar (not same) questions on a google search
[here](http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/133/how-to-use-a-patch-jar-to-override-existing-java-class-files-temporarily/)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909419/overriding-user-library-classes-in-java)

Comment: I doubt that `class public` works in java. Furthermore, I strongly discourage you from naming the child class exactly like the parent class. It's a recipe for unreadable code and painful debugging sessions.

Comment: thanks, i fixed the typo. The requirement is a business requirement, I am trying to find a technical solution to it. Painful debugging sessions is not a priority here at all.

Answer (score 5):

java assist is excellent library for bytecode manipulation. I have modified code below as per your sample code given, You have to explore javaassist more for your actual requirenment

```
CtClass etype = ClassPool.getDefault().get("com.original.library.OriginalLibrary");
// get method from class
CtMethod cm = etype.getDeclaredMethod("getValue");
// change the method bosy
cm.setBody("return 3;");
etype.rebuildClassFile();
// give the path where classes is placed, In my eclipse it is bin
etype.writeFile("bin");


OriginalLibrary originalLibraryObject;
originalLibraryObject = new OriginalLibrary();
System.out.println(originalLibraryObject.getValue());
System.out.println(originalLibraryObject.getAnotherValue());
```

Now output of getValue is 3 because I changed body of that method.

Comment: That may be the way but it will get more complex later on.

Comment: This is a good option, but as @Styl mentioned, it could get more difficult later to accommodate new changes to the existing library.

Comment: Yes it could become complex, Developer must set some pattern and approach before start doing such coding so later he can easily understand the code and modify it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of questions -

- **How is the client getting an instance of your library's class?**
  If they are using `new OriginalLibrary()`, then you're pretty much stuck with creating a new subclass of `OriginalLibrary` and then asking your client to use your new `OriginalLibraryImproved` class. This is a common problem encountered in projects and is one reason why a library should not allow its clients to instantiate its classes directly using the `new` operator.
  If instead, your client is instantiating `OriginalLibrary` using a factory method provided by the library (say, `OriginalLibrary.getInstance()`), you may want to check if there are any hooks into the factory that allow you to change the object being returned.
- **Do you have full control of the source code of the original library?**
  If yes, then you definitely should (and I cannot emphasize this strongly enough) provide factory methods for any class in the library that is instantiable. Doing this allows you to change the actual object being returned without modifying the client (as long as the returned object's class is a subclass of the return value from the factory method).
  If not, then I suggest you do the following.

  - Create a subclass of `OriginalLibrary` (say, `OriginalLibraryImproved`).
  - Create a Factory class named `OriginalLibraryFactory` that has a static method named `getInstance()`. Write code to return an instance of `OriginalLibraryImproved` from this method.
  - Ask your client to replace all occurrences of `new OriginalLibrary()` with `OriginalLibraryFactory.getInstance()`. Note that this approach will only involve adding an extra import for the factory class. The client will still refer to the returned instance using the same `OriginalLibrary` reference as before.

The advantage of this approach is that it gives you complete flexibility to change the implementation details of `OriginalLibraryImproved` without affecting the client in anyway. You could also swap `OriginalLibararyImproved` with a newer version like `OriginalLibraryImprovedVer2` and the client will be oblivious to the fact that it is using a new class. You'll just have to make sure that `OriginalLibraryImprovedVer2` subclasses `OriginalLibrary`.

An even more flexible approach is to use the *Wrapper* or *Decorator* pattern to avoid the pitfalls of inheritance. You can understand more about the Decorator pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

In a nutshell, try to avoid forcing your clients to use `new` and try to avoid inheritance unless you have very compelling reasons.

Comment: He has not integrated a Factory already so what he is asking is not possible, unless he uses reflection.

Comment: Well, asking the client to use a Factory method is still better than asking them to instantiate the subclass directly, don't you think? In any case, some changes need to be made...

Comment: Yeap. You are right. The design must become flexible sooner rather than later.

Comment: The OriginalLibrary does have a factory for creating this object, but I will need to change the factory code, and I cant since that entire code is under LGPL.

Comment: If the factory does not provide a way for developers to change the object being returned, I'd still say you're better off creating your own factory. You could return a decorator that wraps the instance returned by the original factory and only modify those methods that you need different behavior for.